# mock-kue. How do I use it in test mode only

Tags: node.js

Trying to do BDD on my latest node project and am trying to use the mock-kue module.  In the example on the README page the developer never shows where the mock-kue is being required.  I can doe a

> var kue = require('kue')

But I want this to only be in affect when Im running specs/tests and for it to use the normal one when running in production/development.  How would I do this.

Comment: Where did you try to require it? What testing framework do you use? You should put it either into your test files or if you have a global setup file for tests then there.

Comment: I use servertest and should. I require it in my test file at the top level.

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: Please take a look at the [kue-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kue-mock) lib instead. It has a better documentation and prettier API imho...